# Instanciar um objeto de uma classe gerenciada pelo Spring

Tags: spring

Alguém sabe como faço para instanciar um objeto de uma classe gerenciada pelo Spring (Ex: um classe de JPARepository) em uma classe não gerenciada pelo Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de alguma forma acessar o `ApplicationContext` do Spring. Como você disse que essa classe não é gerenciada pelo mesmo, creio que você vai ter que instanciá-lo:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
```

ou se você estiver em uma HttpServlet:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

Vai depender do contexto da sua aplicação. Uma vez que tenha o `context`, obter uma instância é simples:

```
SuaClasse instancia = context.getBean(SuaClasse.class);
```